# Unzip part of file

Tags: linux, csv, gzip

Is there a way to unzip *part* of a `.gz` file without having to unzip it all?

I have a large (~139Gb) zipped `.csv.gz` file. I have been told that the `.csv` file has ~540M rows of data. I only need to access a sample of the data in the `.csv` file and I would be happy for it to be the first 1M rows (which would constitute about ~250Mb of the zip file). I am happy to unzip by number of rows, or by number of bytes, but would prefer to not have to unzip the entire file to access only a sample of the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Untested (I don't have [or care to create] a gzipped CSV file that big):

```
zcat file.csv.gz | head -n 1000000 > extract.csv
```

Comment: It was untested,  so I tested it. Didn't work for me, since not all `head`s have `MB` or `M` suffixes. The edit will work in more places. Also it shouldn't have been `MB` anyway. For lines (`-n`) it should be `M`. What you had would give `head: invalid number of lines: ‘1MB’`. So what was there wouldn't work anywhere.

Comment: Thanks for answering, and "How odd" ... accodring to the man-page for `GNU coreutils 8.30                  September 2019` that should work just fine.